# value of custom product attribute is not storing in database table

Tags: magento, select, attributes, save, box

I am new in Magento and I am using 1.7.2. I added one product attribute called `product type name`. It is a drop down field and values are populated from a different custom table called `product_type_name`. I have done successfully so far. Now I want to store the value of product type name into DB Table while adding a product. For that I have added a column `product_attrb_type_name`(attribute code) in `catalog_product_flat_1` table. 
Now while trying to add the product, it is showing the following error
 `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name ''` 
Also while trying to edit a product, the values are not set in the product entry form.

How to fix this issue? Could you please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses EAV table structure, so once you add a attribute they are stored in eav_attribute table with specific entity type (4 for product).

Now when you load a product object, say

`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load({{entity_id}})` , where entity_id is your product id,

you can use get and set function on this object to set the values of the particular product instance, i.e.

```
$product->setProductTypeName('someValue'); in your case a a dropdown ,so
$product->setProductTypeName(attributeId);
$product->save();
```

and get by

```
$product->getProductTypeName();
```

You do not have to insert in catalog_product_flat tables, that is Magento way to normalize data into flat tables.

Hope it helps!